# how to pass dependent input field variable to recordSelectOptionsQuery() in filament

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I am trying to scope the options based on the input taken from another field. How do I pass this variable inside this `recordSelctOptionQuery`?

```
recordSelectOptionsQuery(
    fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereBelongsTo(
        Item::find('id_selected_from_a_dependent_filed')
))
```

Reference:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/relation-managers#attaching-and-detaching-records